# i am not getting proper data in mysql query.any one can help me?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

i have created [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a6b/3)

[image] and displaying result but i am not getting the second row event pqr .any one can help me please.

i want those rows whose start date and end date if  not null then end_date must be equal or greater today and if current use and maxuses are not null then current use less then max use or all data is null accepting event name and id.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: +1 for using sqlfiddle.

Comment: u want to display the id = 2 , but this id is all null !!

Comment: i want information from table if start dates and end dates are given then end date must be less then or equal from todays date.if max uses is given value then current use must be less then max_uses and if dates are null and max uses are null then get that rows.

Comment: please what result u want get ? only id = 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Select Statement looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE (
     (start_date IS NOT NULL)
  && (end_date IS NOT NULL)
  && (end_date >= curdate())
)
|| (
     (max_use IS NOT NULL)
  && (current_use IS NOT NULL)
  && (current_use < max_use)
);
```

This is not really that what you want. Especially you're completely missing the `or all data is null except event name and id` part. There are still other mistakes (either in your question text or the statement).

The `pqr` row is such a row with all data being null except event name and id.

One other mistake I already corrected is the `greater or equal` part where you checked for just `greater`.

Most probably you want this [statement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66a6b/10):

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE (
     start_date IS NOT NULL
  && end_date IS NOT NULL
  && end_date >= curdate()
)
||(
     max_use IS NOT NULL
  && current_use IS NOT NULL
  && current_use < max_use
)
|| (
     event is not null
  && start_date is null
  && end_date is null
  && max_use is null
  && current_use is null
);
```

Comment: its working perfectly thank you. is there any way to do using joins ?

Comment: Glad to help. Counterquestion: Why do you want to use joins here?

Comment: If you dont mind.i want to know can it be done usings joins ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `WHERE` clauses have a `start_date is not null` constraint (plus some others), and being `start_date` (or every other field) `null` for that record, makes it not to appear in the results.

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you are looking for

```
   select * from event 
  where ((start_date is not null)&&(end_date is not null)&&(end_date>= curdate()))

 OR ((max_use is not null)&&(current_use is not null)&&(current_use < max_use ))
 or ( (start_date is  null ) and (end_date is  null) and (max_use is  null)
   and (current_use is  null))
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0592/4)